# mongoDB collection.findOne() update the query with its own results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query like this one :

```
.findOne( {
    _id: myObjectId,
}, {
    fields: {
        smallSingleValue: 1,
        HUDGE_OBJECT: 1,
    }
} );
```

I do not need the entire `HUDGE_OBJECT` (it is roughly 1 Mo), I need `HUDGE_OBJECT[ smallSingleValue ]` ( less than a Ko ).

Right now, I can make that request and get the entire `HUDGE_OBJECT`, or make two requests ; one the guet the `smallSingleValue` and the other one to get the `HUDGE_OBJECT[ smallSingleValue ]`.

Both solution are crapy.

Is there a way to do something like that :

```
fields: {
    smallSingleValue: 1,
    `HUDGE_OBJECT.${ $smallSingleValue }`: 1,
}
```

Obviously not with that syntax, but you get the idea.

I tried aggregation, but it’s probably not the solution.

Does the projection operator allows it ?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

---

EDIT FOR THE COMMENTS :

Example of data :

```
{
    _id: xxx,
    firstName: xxx,
    lastName: xxx,
    currentLevel: bar, // <- that one is important
    progress: {
        foo: { big object },
        bar: { big object },
        baz: { big object },
        ...
    }
}
```

What I need :

```
{
    firstName: xxx,
    lastName: xxx,
    currentLevel: bar,
    progress: {
        bar: { big object },
    }
}
```

But the question is : performance wise, is it better to just get the entire object (easy query) or to get a truncated object (more complex query but passing a bigger object) ? There are 50 «levels».

I don’ remember what I tried with the aggregation :x but it seemed to be a bad idea.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data you are querying on, and the result you would like to retrieve?

Comment: What was the aggregation you tried? Why didn't it work? That seems like the right approach here since the aggregation framework has a much more expressive projection language.